# How to escape one or more consecutive rows from table, inoutMode either 1 or 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table [My table](http://rextester.com/EJJ23668) with result like as below:

```
Id      EmpCode        CheckInCheckOutDate     WorkDate     InOutMode
85223   175 2017-10-27 11:20:39.000 2017-10-27 11:20:39.000 0
85832   175 2017-10-27 14:21:21.000 2017-10-27 14:21:21.000 1
85844   175 2017-10-27 14:36:23.000 2017-10-27 14:36:23.000 0
85863   175 2017-10-27 15:21:27.000 2017-10-27 15:21:27.000 1
85878   175 2017-10-27 16:03:46.000 2017-10-27 16:03:46.000 0
86031   175 2017-10-27 18:14:41.000 2017-10-27 18:14:41.000 1
86038   175 2017-10-27 18:34:45.000 2017-10-27 18:34:45.000 0
**86039 175 27.10.2017 18:34:46.000 27.10.2017 18:34:46.000 1
86142   175 2017-10-27 19:51:15.000 2017-10-27 19:51:15.000 1**
86162   175 2017-10-27 20:25:44.000 2017-10-27 20:25:44.000 0
86170   175 2017-10-27 20:31:58.000 2017-10-27 20:31:58.000 1
```

and i want to result like below:(after escape the one consecutive row which have same value in "InOutMode" column of consecutive rows either 0 or 1 condition has based on workdate,
Example for : id is '86039' and '86142' row we have same value '1' in last column so I want to remove first 
row and want to have escape only old row.)

```
85223   175 2017-10-27 11:20:39.000 2017-10-27 11:20:39.000 0
85832   175 2017-10-27 14:21:21.000 2017-10-27 14:21:21.000 1
85844   175 2017-10-27 14:36:23.000 2017-10-27 14:36:23.000 0
85863   175 2017-10-27 15:21:27.000 2017-10-27 15:21:27.000 1
85878   175 2017-10-27 16:03:46.000 2017-10-27 16:03:46.000 0
86031   175 2017-10-27 18:14:41.000 2017-10-27 18:14:41.000 1
86038   175 2017-10-27 18:34:45.000 2017-10-27 18:34:45.000 0
86142   175 2017-10-27 19:51:15.000 2017-10-27 19:51:15.000 1
86162   175 2017-10-27 20:25:44.000 2017-10-27 20:25:44.000 0
86170   175 2017-10-27 20:31:58.000 2017-10-27 20:31:58.000 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  select * ,SUM(CASE WHEN InOutMode=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) -- SUM(1-InOutMode)
            OVER(PARTITION BY EmpCode ORDER BY ID) s
  from test1
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpCode, s ORDER BY id) as rn
  FROM cte 
), cte3 AS (
   SELECT *, MAX(rn) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpCode, s) AS m
   FROM cte2
)
DELETE FROM cte3
WHERE rn > 1 AND rn <> m;

SELECT *
FROM test1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/YCECK51281)**

Intermediate result to illustrate idea (flip-flop):

[image]

If you need you could add futher partitions (for example by day).

Comment: @ad2025 thank you for your response but, I want to escape row id:86039 instead of 86142 always want data greater than  workdate.

Comment: @GoutamSingh Please check once again more carefully this time.

Comment: instead of `CASE WHEN InOutMode=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`, you could use `1-InOutMode`

Comment: @ad2025 Hi, This code though error message:" Incorrect syntax near 'order'.Incorrect syntax near ','." in SQL server 2008 r2 can you please resolve this thanks Goutam