# Get an Error, while i am trying to imiliment escape one or more consecutive rows from table, inoutMode either 1 or 0 in SqlServer 2008r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have get error [Reference Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038495/how-to-escape-one-or-more-consecutive-rows-from-table-inoutmode-either-1-or-0/47038674?noredirect=1#comment81025024_47038674) while query put in Sql Server 2008r2 then get error like : [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fai1.png)

My query is : http://rextester.com/YCECK51281

Comment: Post your query....

Comment: @scsimon here is my query : http://rextester.com/YCECK51281